# How to add Ogg Skeleton 4 to an Ogg Theora file with oggz?

Tags: untagged

The [man page for oggz](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/oggz-tools/oggz.1.en.html) reads:

```
[Oggz] can read and write Ogg Skeleton logical bitstreams.
```

I have attempted the following:

```
oggz-merge -o test-out.ogv test-in.theo.ogv
oggz-sort -o test-out.ogv test-in.theo.ogv
```

Both of them write a new Ogg video file with all the streams intact, but I do not see a Skeleton track being added. I have checked man pages, and cannot find anything akin to `addskel` of `hogg`.

---

I have now also tried ripping the tracks (I have 3) with:

```
oggz-rip -o test-out.ogv -i 0 -i 1 -i 2 test-in.theo.ogv
```

This has not created a skeleton track either.